# How to convert a single MySql table to utf8mb4 (from latin1)

Tags: mysql-5.6

MySql version 5.6.39

i have one table that now needs to support chinese characters. the other tables in the database do not need utf8mb4 encoding.

what have i done thus far:
1) backed up database!
2) alter table `<blah>` default character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
3) alter table `<blah>` convert to character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
4) (for all columns except numeric) alter table `<blah>` change col1 col1 varchar(xx) character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

what i have not done thus far:
1) alter database `<blahDB>` character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

i've seen several questions/answers here...notibly:
[How to easily convert utf8 tables to utf8mb4 in MySQL 5.5](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8239/how-to-easily-convert-utf8-tables-to-utf8mb4-in-mysql-5-5)  Is it necessary to alter the database when all i want is for one table within it to be utf8mb4?

Right now, when i insert a "special" (unicode) char (0x2015) in the middle of a string into the table, it is stored as '?'. Help!!

Comment: Do the changes to the columns show correctly when investigating the schema?
`SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM <blah>;`

Comment: Yes! they all (except the "Id" numeric type column) show "utf8mb4_unicode_ci" collation.

Comment: How are you interacting with MySQL? If it's via an external client is the connection able to handle the characters?
This link may help:
[https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4]

Comment: i have a java program that issues the relevant sql functions (INSERT, SELECT, etc). Lemme read that article...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going by what you have to do within a PHP-Webserver environment to use utf8 / utf8mb4, you have up to 5 or more construction places. And you covered 2 of them

- collation of table and column(s)
- overwork existing string-data in said columns

leaves:

- make sure your application / tool uses the correct collation as well
- make sure you communicate with the database using the correct collation
- set the frontend of your application / tool to handle said collation

As JAVA is well prepared I guess its the database connection ...

Comment: in the Java code i had to convert the offending String to bytes("UTF8") prior to storing in the table. i had to reverse the conversion when i selected the record from the table. It works! thanks!